# windows 7, cannot invoke exe from bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

In windows 7 a bat file was made:

```
rem set UD_LOG_FILE_PATH=%temp%\defrag_native.log
C:
cd \Windows\System32
udefrag.exe --optimize-mft C:
udefrag.exe -o C:
pause
```

I can double click the bat file and it runs OK. However, the bat file was made to be invoked from a running program. When the program shells out to the bat file the following error is produced:

'C:\Windows\System32\udefrag.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Invocation is done using Shell in VB6. Different things were tried. First the bat file was called directly, then with C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c, then with C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /c. All produce the same result. The bat file runs but will not run the exe file within the bat file. But the bat file works OK if run directly. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Is `udefrag.exe` actually in that folder? Or are you in fact running a command prompt that has a particular `PATH` variable that just happens to work when you launch your bat file directly?

Comment: Yes, udefrag.exe is in the same folder.

Comment: So to confirm, if you hi Start/Run and type `C:\Windows\System32\udefrag.exe`, it runs successfully? If that's the case then I'd suspect you're looking at a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used task scheduler to resolve this. A task was created with no trigger named "defragment". The task invokes the bat file. Instead of invoking the bat file from the running program the following command is given:

schtasks /Run /TN defragment

This runs the bat file through the task scheduler. I don't know why I have to do it that way, but it works good.

Answer (score 1):

Google says that udefrag.exe is a third party program.  If it is in c:\windows\system32 then it is on the path and you only need the last 3 lines in your batch file.  Try this first and see if it needs elevated permissions.   If you have UAC turned off then turn it back on for the test.  Your VB program may not have the right permissions.

```
@echo off
udefrag.exe --optimize-mft C:
udefrag.exe -o C:
pause
```

Comment: I have deleted my answer as after testing this at home I am happy to conceed that you do end up at the same directory either way. I can also see your point that this shouldn't matter as it's in the PATH envioronment variable anyway. Probably the only useful part was that you --can-- replace two commands such as `c:` and `cd \Windows\System32` with a single command such as `cd /d c:\Windows\System32`, but as in this instance neither should be required.

Comment: I tried using cd /d. No difference. I didn't think it would but I tried anyway. When the bat file is called, if I look at the DOS window before it changes, I notice the path is \users\administrator. I am not logged in as administrator, but I do have UAC completely turned off. I am never prompted for administrator permission on anything. If it was a permission problem wouldn't it say that? I don't think it's permission, but a block to prevent calling an exe from the bat file. I could call the exe directly instead of using the bat file but need to use the bat file.

Comment: A) did you try the batch file.  B) did you enable UAC and try it.  You can then tell me it is not permissions, but without trying it you are ignoring the advice that you are asking for.  Some UAC prompts fail silently - you can also right click the batch file and run with elevated permissions, to test it.